# Exodus 33:11 Moses saw God face to face as a friend. John 1:17,18 Jesus said “No one has seen God.” Who should I believe

Tags: contradiction

- Exodus 33:11 - Moses said he saw God face to face as a friend.
- John 1:17,18 - For the Law was given by Moses (does not say God), but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ. No man has seen God at any time.
- Acts 7:53 - Law given by angels.

Jesus said no man has seen God, but many Patriarchs said they saw God. It is obvious who we should believe. An angel impersonating God -- maybe the god of this world -- gave the law to Moses.

- YHWH did many apparently evil things, claiming to be God.
- 1 Corinthians 13 -- What love is like, and God is Love.
- Check out YouTube channel Good God for evidence from scripture.

**My Questions**

1. Can you picture Jesus doing the evil things YHWH has done?
2. Is the Father the same person as the Son?

Comment: A neat Marcionite take on it.

Comment: Edward, you have asked several questions, not just one.  It would be very difficult for anyone to answer all of them in one post.  They are answerable.  If you would, please choose the one question you would like answered, and edit this.

Comment: This is just an advert for a 'GoFundMe' [enterprise](https://uk.gofundme.com/dominion-bible-ministries).

Comment: John 1:18 is simply referencing Exodus 33:20-23, from the same chapter as the quote you provided. Furthermore, Matthew 5:8 also speaks of seeing God. Basically, Exodus 33:11, just like Numbers 12:6-8, contrasts dreams with actual physical sight, whereas Exodus 33:20-23 and John 1:18 contrast (or discern between) various levels of physical sightings of the divine.

Comment: I have edited to make your post more readable. I doubt very strongly that you are interested in an answer to your questions, since your post is nothing more than rhetoric. It will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Wow - you have raised several matters here that are rather fundamental to understanding Scriptural hermeneutics.  So let me take these one at a time.

**1. Seeing God**

Lets begin with the Prologue to the Gospel of John and John's summary in the final verse (John 1:18) "no one has ever seen God [the Father] but the one and only (= Gr: monogenes) God … has revealed him."  Thus, to be absolutely pedantic, this text is using your very contradiction to explain that the Father remains veiled while the Son is revealed (also v14).  There is a similar dichotomy in John 14 where Philip asks to see the Father but Jesus responds by say you have seen me!

There are a number of places where people reported seeing YHWH such as Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1, and the encounter is called an angel (=messenger).  Which member of the Godhead is not stated but on the basis of the data in John's Gospel, it may have been Jesus, but this is NOT stated.

**2. Divine Passive**

The concept of the Divine passive is well documented in many other places so here I will be brief.  Compare 1 Sam 24:1 with 1 Chron 21:1.  Who tempted King David to have a census? God or Satan?  Both are correct because to the Hebrew mind, God is omniscient and omnipotent and thus events only occur if He allows.  James 1:13 explicitly states that God tempts no one.  In 1 Sam 16:14, 16, 18:10, 19:9 – God sent an evil (literally, unclean) spirit on Saul?  God does not have an evil spirit to send!  Again, the omnipotent God is deemed responsible for that which He does not prevent.  Judges 9:23 has an identical idea of an evil spirit from God.

We MUST understand scripture in the language and idiom of the those who wrote not ours.  To the Hebrew mind, because God is omniscient and omnipotent He is capable of doing anything and preventing anything: therefore, he is responsible for that which he does not prevent  Thus the Hebrews often laid the responsibility for "bad" things with God when other (often satanic or human) forces were really responsible.

Answer (score 1):

This response addresses your initial question about the apparent conflict between Exodus 33:11 and John 1:17-18.

The reference to the phrase “face to face” in Exodus 33 is an idiom and not to be taken literally. The idea is that Moses had a close relationship with God as a close friend.  This is what is being conveyed and not the literal viewing of God’s face.

In Exodus 24, the bible tells us that a cloud covered the top of the mount and that Moses entered into that cloud. 
Exodus 24:15-18 (KJV21):

> 15 And Moses went up onto the mount, and a cloud covered the mount. 16
>   And the glory of the Lord abode upon Mount Sinai, and the cloud
>   covered it six days; and the seventh day He called unto Moses out of
>   the midst of the cloud. 17 And the sight of the glory of the Lord was
>   like devouring fire on the top of the mount in the eyes of the
>   children of Israel. 18 And Moses went into the midst of the cloud, and
>   got himself up onto the mount; and Moses was on the mount forty days
>   and forty nights.

So, we see that the cloud acted as a veil where Moses was prevented from actually seeing the face of God. That’s why in Exodus 33 when Moses asks to see God’s full glory, God responds by saying that he could not see God’s face and live. Hence, God only revealed His receding glory to Moses.

Exodus 33:18-20 (KJV21):

> 18 And he said, “I beseech Thee, show me Thy glory.” 19 And He said,
>   “I will make all My goodness pass before thee; and I will proclaim the
>   name of the LORD before thee, and will be gracious to whom I will be
>   gracious, and will show mercy on whom I will show mercy.” 20 And He
>   said, “Thou canst not see My face, for there shall no man see Me and
>   live.” 21 And the LORD said, “Behold, there is a place by Me, and thou
>   shalt stand upon a rock. 22 And it shall come to pass, while My glory
>   passeth by, that I will put thee in a cleft of the rock, and will
>   cover thee with My hand while I pass by; 23 and I will take away Mine
>   hand, and thou shalt see My back parts, but My face shall not be
>   seen.”

Comment: Face is used as a Hebrew idiom to mean in the presents of.  The Exodus 33 passage is what I immediately thought of when reading this question.

Comment: ...presence....

Answer (score 0):

Moses have not seen God face to face,quoting ,John 1:18) "no one has ever seen God [the Father] The only Son,who is the same as God and is at the Father's side, he has made him known.